# Tizen SDK .NET TV Visual Studio LLDB

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, tizen

I'm currently trying the new Samsung Tizen .NET TV Framework for Visual Studio.
I've followed the instructions to install it and created a basic application to test it.

But when I try to launch the app on the emulator (or on real TV), I've got the following error:

> Unable to start debugging. Unable to establish a connection to LLDB. The following message was written to stderr: closed. See Output Window for details.

In the Output Window I've got the following message for the emulator:

```
Starting: "C:\tizen-studio\tools\sdb.exe"  -s emulator-26101 shell sh -c 'launch_app org.tizen.example.TizenVisualTest.Tizen.TV   __AUL_SDK__ LLDB-SERVER __DLP_DEBUG_ARG__ g,--platform=host,*:1234,-- CORECLR_GDBJIT TizenVisualTest.dll,TizenVisualTest.Tizen.TV.dll;/home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/lldb/bin/lldb-mi'
closed
"C:\tizen-studio\tools\sdb.exe" exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

And for TV:

```
Starting: "C:\tizen-studio\tools\sdb.exe"  -s 10.20.1.79:26101 shell sh -c 'launch_app org.tizen.example.TizenVisualTest.Tizen.TV   __AUL_SDK__ LLDB-SERVER __DLP_DEBUG_ARG__ g,--platform=host,*:1234,-- CORECLR_GDBJIT TizenVisualTest.dll,TizenVisualTest.Tizen.TV.dll;/lldb/bin/lldb-mi'
... launch failed
sh: /lldb/bin/lldb-mi: No such file or directory
"C:\tizen-studio\tools\sdb.exe" exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after more investigations and tests with SDB command, I've found out that there's here two different problems:

1. For the emulator: the platform wasn't correctly configured in emulator manager - it was set to tv-samsung-4.0 instead of tv-4.0 wich seemed to cause the error
2. For the TV: the Tizen SDK version of my device is 2.4 or the .NET SDK is for 4.0 or more